# How to make Bottle refuse too big uploaded files?

Tags: python, apache, upload, mod-wsgi, bottle

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296741/1422096) is a way to accept upload with Bottle:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

and

```
from bottle import route, request

@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    myfile = request.files.get('file')
    size = len(myfile.read())  # oops the file is already read anyway!
    if size > 1024*1024:  # 1 MB
        return "File too big"
```

However, with this technique a 500 MB file would be read anyway, *before* noticing it's a "too big file".

**Question: how to prevent a Bottle server to even accept a too big uploaded file, without having to read it first (and waste bandwidth/memory!)?**

If not possible with Bottle only, how to do it with Apache + `mod_wsgi` (I currently use this)?

Comment: You can first read header "Content-Length" to determine drop it or not. But you cannot avoid wasting bandwidth.

Comment: @Sraw when reading "Content-Length", the 500 MB would already be uploaded to server, so that's too late, the file is already on server, isn't there a way to know this earlier and refuse it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible in pure bottle. Maybe you should consider to use nginx as a frontend server which is usually used in production.

Comment: @Sraw I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi, would you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Apache, you can add to the Apache configuration the `LimitRequestBody` directive and specify the limit. The request will be rejected before it even gets to your Python code.

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody